# Best way to list subcategories on a Django template (ManyRelatedManager not Iterable)

Tags: python, django

I am building an app for displaying events.

The events model looks like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    venue = models.ForeignKey('venues.Venue')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('categories.Category')
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Note: the event can have multiple categories.

The categories model looks like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Note:  A main category would be defined as a category that has no "parent_category"

This allows me to have hierarchical categories like this:

```
Music
    Vallenato
    Rock Latino
    Cumbia
```

Now on a Django template I want to present a list off all the events for a given **main category** (like a listview).

Using the same example, this page would consist of:

-A list with an overview of all of the music events so people can get a brief of the events and click on one to get a detail of a given event.

When I send the event queryset to the template like this:

```
events = Event.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

And I try to loop over the event categories with something like this:

```
{% for event in events %}
    {% for category in event.categories %}
```

I get a **ManyRelatedManager not Iterable** error.

What is the best way to list all the subcategories of a given event on a template?

How would you handle this at the template or view level? (whichever is best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, it's a manager, so you need to use manager methods on it: `{% for category in event.categories.all %}`.

Comment: thanks, I have edited the model so that it says categories instead of category, I will try to use the .all and get back to you.

Comment: that was it! all I was missing was the .all